# how do I keep the menu displayed while the mouse pointer is hovering the menu div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made this menu where the person needs to position the mouse pointer over the item in the upper right corner of the screen. However, when I drag the pointer, the menu is gone.

I need help to know how to fix this menu while the mouse pointer is still in the menu area, it remains active and only disappears when the user drags the mouse pointer out of that area.

```js
function apareceMenu()
{
    document.querySelector(".menu").style.display = 'block';
}

function someMenu()
{
document.querySelector(".menu").style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'california';
    src: url('font/Hai_California.ttf');
    src: url('Hai_California?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('font/Hai_California.ttf') format('svg'),
      url('font/Hai_California.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    /* 
    
        Usa uma fonte externa (baixada ou internet) e disponibiliza para que 
        caso o usuário não tenha a mesma instalada na sua máquina, seja feito o
        download da fonte.
    
    
    */
  }
html, body {
        background-color: #ffff;   
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}
img.menu_icon {
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
}
.menu_icon:hover .menu {
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: -1;
}
img.logo {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1366px;
    height: 220px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: rgb(245,183,46);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(245,183,46,1) 0%, rgba(249,219,92,1) 100%);
    color: black;
}
.menu {
    opacity: 0.75;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1366px;
    height: 220px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #cc444b;
    color: white;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
.menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
.menu1 { 
    margin-left: 30px;
}
#header h1 {
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.logo {
    margin-top: -250px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}
/*

    Centraliza a imaem dentro do header

*/
.logo_nome {
    margin-top: auto;
}
.logo_nome a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.conteiner img {
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 150px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 7px #6b722d;
    font-size:  70px;
    font-family: california, cursive;
}
.linha {
    height: 13px;
    margin-top: 76px;
    color: #cc444b;
    background-color: #cc444b;
    border-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br"> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="sortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="fotos/logo.png"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" >
        <title>Sal de Ouro</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="menu" onmouseout="someMenu()">
            <div class="menu1">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Teste</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Teste</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Teste</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Teste</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Texte</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </nav>
        <div id="header">
            <img class="menu_icon" onmouseover="apareceMenu()" src="fotos/menu.png" >
            <h1>Sal de Ouro</h1>
            <img class="logo" src="fotos/logo.png" /> 
            <hr class="linha">
        </div> 
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: mouseleave is better than mouseout

Comment: why use JS for such thing if you could simply use the `:hover` selector in CSS?

Comment: Use this: https://jsfiddle.net/4981vdwy/ (solved by moving the appearing element inside the hovered one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this only using CSS, and no JavaScript.

You need a container around your whole navigation, including the icon. (I used `<nav>` here)

```
      <nav>
        <img class="menu_icon" src="fotos/menu.png">
        <div class='menu'>
          <div class="menu1">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Teste</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Teste</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Teste</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Teste</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Texte</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

The CSS:

```
.menu {
  display: none;
}

nav:hover .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

This CSS hides `.menu`. It then displays `.menu` it if anywhere on the navigation is being hovered over.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'california';
    src: url('font/Hai_California.ttf');
    src: url('Hai_California?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('font/Hai_California.ttf') format('svg'),
      url('font/Hai_California.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    /* 
    
        Usa uma fonte externa (baixada ou internet) e disponibiliza para que 
        caso o usuário não tenha a mesma instalada na sua máquina, seja feito o
        download da fonte.
    
    
    */
  }
html, body {
        background-color: #ffff;   
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}
img.menu_icon {
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
}
img.logo {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1366px;
    height: 220px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: rgb(245,183,46);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(245,183,46,1) 0%, rgba(249,219,92,1) 100%);
    color: black;
}
.menu {
    opacity: 0.75;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1366px;
    height: 220px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #cc444b;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
}
.menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
.menu1 { 
    margin-left: 30px;
}
#header h1 {
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.logo {
    margin-top: -250px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}
/*

    Centraliza a imaem dentro do header

*/
.logo_nome {
    margin-top: auto;
}
.logo_nome a {
    color: black;
}

/* NEW PART */
.menu {
  display: none;
}

nav:hover .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
          <nav>
            <img class="menu_icon" src="fotos/menu.png">
            <div class='menu'>
              <div class="menu1">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Teste</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Teste</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Teste</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Teste</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Texte</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <h1>Sal de Ouro</h1>
          <img class="logo" src="fotos/logo.png" /> 
          <hr class="linha">
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```